# Strange behaviour with primefaces datetable nested on JSF portlet

Tags: jsf, primefaces

On a Liferay plugin project I've got a JSF+PF based portlet on which I've created a minimal, complete, and verifiable example dealing with `<p:dataTable>`  and `<p:rowExpansion>` elements which are working weirdly. The code is the one as follws:

.xhtml side:

```
<h:form id="entityGuidesForm">
  <p:panel>
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
      <p:column style="width:15px">
        <p:rowToggler />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="name">
        <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:dataTable value="#{bean.subitems}" var="subitem">
          <p:column headerText="subname">
            <h:outputText value="#{subitem}" />
          </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

That is, a date table displaying some rows, each row showing a nested table.

bean side:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable { 

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Bean.class);

    private String[] items;
    private String[] subitems;

    public Bean() {
        logger.trace("bean created");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void onPostConstruct() {

        logger.trace("start");
        try {
            items = new String[1];
            items[0] = "0";             

            subitems = new String[1];
            subitems[0] = "0.1";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String[] getItems() {

        logger.trace("start");
        return this.items;
    }

    public void setItems(String[] items) {

        logger.trace("start");
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String[] getSubitems() {

        logger.trace("start");
        return this.subitems;
    }

    public void setSubitems(String[] subitems) {

        logger.trace("start");
        this.subitems = subitems;
    }
```

When the page containing that portlet gets rendered, the logger throws this log:

```
[TRACE] Bean:<init>():bean created
[TRACE] Bean:onPostConstruct():start
[TRACE] Bean:getItems():start
[TRACE] Bean:getItems():start
```

Although it seems weird to me that the `getItems()` method is called two times, the weirdest thing comes when I click on the `<p:rowToggler />` element, getting this log:

```
[TRACE] Bean:getItems():start

...  //15 times as the previous line, 17 times overall

[TRACE] Bean:getItems():start
[TRACE] Bean:getSubitems():start
[TRACE] Bean:getSubitems():start
[TRACE] Bean:getItems():start
[TRACE] Bean:getItems():start
```

I don't know why the `getItems()` method is called 17 times before the `getSubitems()` method is called. It's not a major problem on this example, but in my real example the `getItems()` method implies accesing a database and I would like to avoid it as much as I can.

Any clarification on what's happening would be appreciated, as well as a possible solution. Thanks.

Comment: _"I don't know why the getItems() method is called 17 times before the"_ : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times.

Comment: You can buy I can also mark it as a duplicate...